# Sorting output in C shell

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I have a script that I am writing in tcsh.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

set sublen = `echo $1 | wc -c`
@ sublen = $sublen + 10
echo Grades for $1
echo =================
grep -wr --include=?????????.std $1 * | cut -d " " -f 2 | sort -rn
```

with the output looking like this:

```
Grades for <$1>
=================
<arbitrary 2nd field>
<arbitrary 2nd field>
<arbitrary 2nd field>
```

However I want it to also output the file name (minus the ".std") before each sorted line. So it would look more like this:

```
Grades for <$1>
=================
111111111    <arbitrary 2nd field>
222222222    <arbitrary 2nd field>
333333333    <arbitrary 2nd field>
```

I've been trying to use a script split in 2 parts, one for printing the lines using a loop and another to sort them, but that causes errors whenever the argument does not match any lines in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time for you to go on a 2 Step Recovery Program:

1. Repent thy evil ways — or, at least, renounce the heresy of trying to script in C shell (see [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)).
2. Don't cut out information that you need:

   ```
   grep -wr --include=?????????.std $1 * | sed 's/\.std:/ /' | sort -k 2rn
   ```

   The `sed` command removes the `.std` from the file name and the colon that `grep` adds, replacing that with a space to separate the base filename from the value.  The `sort` command sorts on the second field, in reverse numeric order, just as you previously sorted on the first (only) field in reverse numeric order.

Since the correct operation of the script depends on the filename being included by `grep`, and since `grep` doesn't include the filename by default when you only specify one file to scan, it might be worth using:

```
    grep -wr --include=?????????.std $1 /dev/null * | sed 's/\.std:/ /' | sort -k 2rn
```

Adding `/dev/null` ensures that there are always at least two filenames on the command line, so you always get the filenames output by `grep`, but you won't get any matches from `/dev/null`.  Some versions of `grep` have an option to specify 'always output the filename', one such option on Mac OS X being `-H`.  Check the man page for your `grep`.

Comment: that really helps! thank you!. although, I do need to keep the cut command in there, just change it a little with the current changes made.  the field I am cutting out is the field with the pattern that grep searches for, but it is not needed in the final output.
so now the code looks like:
`grep -wr --include=?????????.std $1 /dev/null * | sed 's/\.std:/ /' | cut -d " " -f1,3 | sort -k 2rn`
and now the output is what I need it to be :)
P.S.  I wouldn't use c shell, except that it is part of the requirement
P.S.S.If I wasn't so new to the site, I would up vote you :)

Comment: Sometimes, you have to kowtow to the people in charge. Nevertheless, as a long-term goal, I think it is sensible for you to use POSIX shell (`bash`, `ksh`, etc) rather than C shell for scripting. If you need just selected information from the data, then you do still need a modified version of `cut`; well done on taking the help from this answer and producing what you need. (It is surprising how often those asking questions find that the answer isn't producing exactly what they need and complain until it is amended into doing exactly what they require. Some sense of over-entitlement, perhaps.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sadly, there are some situations where you have to write in csh.  At my work, there is a script that sets environment variables, but *only* csh.  I need those environment variables to call other programs in my scripts, so I am essentially required to use csh (The frustrating thing is no one warned me beforehand, and I wrote it in bash first, then had to translate to csh).  I wouldn't be surprised if most people that post on SO know that csh is bad, they just are being forced to use it by the man.

Comment: I've worked with colleagues who haven't seen the light, and needed to use their csh environment setting scripts. I would usually exec `csh`, `source their-script.csh`, then `exec bash` (or `exec ksh`). You might be able to adapt that: `printf "source their-script.csh\nexec bash -i\n" > my-script.sh;` followed by `csh ./my-script.sh` (or, when you're sure it works, `exec csh ./my-script.sh`). Or some variant on that. Basically, replace your shell with `csh` for long enough to set the environment, then replace the `csh` with your shell again. Of course, this doesn't work so well with aliases.

Comment: That's one of many reasons why I don't use aliases if I can possibly help it.  I don't like shell 'environment setting' scripts that load up the environment with hundreds of functions that I don't know about, much less use, either.